# Memory-bandwidth limited and computation-limited applications of GPU

Tags: gpgpu, gpu, memory-bandwidth

In studying GPUs and applications that utilize them, the terms 'memory-bandwidth limited' and 'computation limited' are often used without defining them rigorously.(or explaining what they are)

I've got 2 questions on this matter.

1. If an application is memory-bandwidth limited, does it mean that the application would run much faster (the bottleneck is the memory access bandwidth) with better memory access speed? And if an application is computation-limited, does it mean it would show much higher performance if it had more computation resources, or faster computation? As in reducing the latency of a single operation and having more ALU units)
2. If what I understand is true, most of today's applications are memory-bandwidth limited, rather than computation-limited. Has this always been the case since the popular use of GPUs?

Comment: 1. yes. yes. 2. It depends on the GPU and its use case but probably most applications are bw limited. And regarding the question: I don't know. What year are you thinking when saying "since the popular use of GPUs"? (This second question is a history question and no programming question btw)

Comment: @Shadow I don't have a specific year in mind, but I'm thinking since the 'Deep Learning' boom, but I'm not certain since I don't really have any knowledge on whether the first implementations of AlexNet, VGG, or any other deep neural networks have made use of GPUs. I thought people who have been in this programming field would know about this issue and had to ask here, though I do agree it is a history question.  Thanks for the answer.

Comment: GTX 8800 ultra: 86 GB/s and 300 GFLOPS

GT 1030: 48 GB/s and 1127 GFLOPS

Ratios of compute/mem are 3.5 and 23.4. Very different. If your algorithm is balanced on value of "10" for compute/mem ratio, then it could act like compute-bottlenecked on the GTX8800ultra and memory-bottlenecked on the GT1030. One may say "it looks like memory-bottlenecked on my GT1030" and after finding a GTX8800 ultra may say "no, its compute-bottlenecked and is slower now". Especially when algorithm is tuned for the hardware.

Comment: Of course it is not only application but also device and implementation dependent. And then there is the question if one should consider "gaming GPUs" or only "server GPUs" (which you should really think about if you need double precision). I personally almost always hit the memory bandwidth wall way before getting even near to reaching max flop rates (I don't do ML stuff so I cannot tell you about their problems). And don't forget the possible problem of a small vram and the bottlenecks coming from workarounds.